# React - how to add dynamic key/value pair to an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying to add dynamic key/value pair to an initial object with the appendInput() function.

**Initial object:**

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  milestonesValues : {
    milestone0: "dssdsad",
    milestone1: "",
    milestone2: "",
    milestone3: "",
  }
};
```

}

**The render method:**

```
render(){
return(
  <div>
    <main className="content">
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className="input-wrap">
          <label>{'What are the basic steps?'}
            {Object.keys(this.state.milestonesValues).map( (milestone, index) =>
              <input
                key={milestone}
                placeholder={`${index+1}.` }
                type="text"
                name={milestone}
                value={this.state.milestonesValues[milestone]}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
              )}
          </label>
          <button onClick={ () => this.appendInput() }>
            {"+ ADD MILESTONE"}
          </button>
        </div>
       </form>
     </main>
   </div>
);
```

**appendInput() function:**

```
  appendInput() {
var objectSize = Object.keys(this.state.milestonesValues).length;
var newInput = `milestone${objectSize}: "",`;

console.log(newInput);
this.setState({
  milestonesValues: this.state.milestonesValues.concat([newInput])
});
```

}

and I just can't add the new generated key/value to that initial object.

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using [computed expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (I'm not really sure if you are trying to do that already). So your `appendInput` function should look something like this:

```js
appendInput() {
  var objectSize = Object.keys(this.state.milestonesValues).length;
  var newInput = Object.assign({}, 
this.state.milestonesValues, {['milestone'+ objectSize]: ''});
  this.setState({
    milestonesValues: newInput)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
appendInput() {
    var milestonesValues = Object.assign({}, this.state.milestonesValues);

    var objectSize = Object.keys(milestonesValues).length;
    var newInput = `milestone${objectSize}`;

    milestonesValues[newInput] = '';

    this.setState({ milestonesValues });
}
```

Check this example:

```js
let data = {
  milestonesValues : {
    milestone0: "dssdsad",
    milestone1: "",
    milestone2: "",
    milestone3: "",
  }
};

function addelement(){
   var milestonesValues = Object.assign({}, data.milestonesValues);

    var objectSize = Object.keys(milestonesValues).length;
    var newInput = `milestone${objectSize}`;

    milestonesValues[newInput] = '';

    data.milestonesValues = milestonesValues;
}

addelement();

console.log(data.milestonesValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newInput = Object.assign({},
this.state.products.map(function(addNewfield){ addNewfield[val]= '' }));
this.setState({ products: newInput })
```

Comment: while this code may answer the question, adding some explanations on why and how would improve the quality of the answer